# Background image gets cut off

Tags: html, css, background-image

I'm trying to get a PNG image as the background image visible on an HTML page with no cut-offs. I've been attempting to use different simple methods found online and read the responses to similar questions on Stack Overflow, but nothing's worked so far. The image is cutting off about halfway in. I'm not sure if it's an issue with my HTML/CSS or the size of my image?

```css
<style type="text/css" style="display: none !important;">
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    #demo-top-bar {
        text-align: left;
        background: #222;
        position: relative;
        zoom: 1;
        width: 100% !important;
        z-index: 6000;
        padding: 20px 0 20px;
    }
    #demo-bar-inside {
        width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #demo-bar-buttons {
        padding-top: 10px;
        float: right;
    }
    #demo-bar-buttons a {
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        color: white;
        margin: 2px 0;
        text-decoration: none;
        font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif !important;
    }
    #demo-bar-buttons a:hover,
    #demo-bar-buttons a:focus {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    #demo-bar-badge {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 302px;
        padding: 0 !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
        background-color: transparent !important;
    }
    #demo-bar-badge a {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 38px;
        border-radius: 0;
        bottom: auto;
        margin: 0;
        background: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56fecd9704426225f7725b25/58699484197aea5283447865/59cf2b839f74567b7edf839d/1506750164505/votepledge_comingsoonpage_final_1920.png) no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-indent: -9999px;
    }
    #demo-bar-badge:before, #demo-bar-badge:after {
        display: none !important;
    }

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> votepledge :) </title>
    <style>
        * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

        html, body { height: 100%; }

        html { 
            background: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56fecd9704426225f7725b25/58699484197aea5283447865/59cf2b839f74567b7edf839d/1506750164505/votepledge_comingsoonpage_final_1920.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
            -webkit-background-size: cover;
            -moz-background-size: cover;
            -o-background-size: cover;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        #page-wrap { width: 400px; margin: 50px auto; padding: 20px; background: white; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black; box-shadow: 0 0 20px black; }
        p { font: 15px/2 Georgia, Serif; margin: 0 0 30px 0; text-indent: 40px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: Do you mean that your image at bottom gets cut ?

Comment: It's normal that your image gets cropped. There are a lot of display sizes.  So the best is to separate the text and the background so the text will never  be cut out

Answer (score 0):

Is this how you wanted it ?

```css
<style type="text/css" style="display: none !important;">
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
    #demo-top-bar {
        text-align: left;
        background: #222;
        position: relative;
        zoom: 1;
        width: 100% !important;
        z-index: 6000;
        padding: 20px 0 20px;
    }
    #demo-bar-inside {
        width: 960px;
        margin: 0 auto;
        position: relative;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
    #demo-bar-buttons {
        padding-top: 10px;
        float: right;
    }
    #demo-bar-buttons a {
        font-size: 12px;
        margin-left: 20px;
        color: white;
        margin: 2px 0;
        text-decoration: none;
        font: 14px "Lucida Grande", Sans-Serif !important;
    }
    #demo-bar-buttons a:hover,
    #demo-bar-buttons a:focus {
        text-decoration: underline;
    }
    #demo-bar-badge {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 302px;
        padding: 0 !important;
        margin: 0 !important;
        background-color: transparent !important;
    }
    #demo-bar-badge a {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        height: 38px;
        border-radius: 0;
        bottom: auto;
        margin: 0;
        background: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56fecd9704426225f7725b25/58699484197aea5283447865/59cf2b839f74567b7edf839d/1506750164505/votepledge_comingsoonpage_final_1920.png) no-repeat;
        background-size: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-indent: -9999px;
    }
    #demo-bar-badge:before, #demo-bar-badge:after {
        display: none !important;
    }

</body>
</html>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title> votepledge :) </title>
    <style>
        * { margin: 0; padding: 0; }

        html, body { height: 100%; }

        html { 
            background: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56fecd9704426225f7725b25/58699484197aea5283447865/59cf2b839f74567b7edf839d/1506750164505/votepledge_comingsoonpage_final_1920.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-size: 100vw 100vh;
            background-attachment: fixed;
            height: 40em;
            margin-top: 0;
            padding: 0;
           }            
  

        #page-wrap { width: 400px; margin: 50px auto; padding: 20px; background: white; -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black; -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black; box-shadow: 0 0 20px black; }
        p { font: 15px/2 Georgia, Serif; margin: 0 0 30px 0; text-indent: 40px; }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define `background-size` in many different ways. Here are two example

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  background: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56fecd9704426225f7725b25/58699484197aea5283447865/59cf2b839f74567b7edf839d/1506750164505/votepledge_comingsoonpage_final_1920.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: contain;
}

#page-wrap {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: white;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
}

p {
  font: 15px/2 Georgia, Serif;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  text-indent: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> votepledge :) </title>

</head>

<body></body></html>
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  background: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56fecd9704426225f7725b25/58699484197aea5283447865/59cf2b839f74567b7edf839d/1506750164505/votepledge_comingsoonpage_final_1920.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#page-wrap {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  padding: 20px;
  background: white;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px black;
}

p {
  font: 15px/2 Georgia, Serif;
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
  text-indent: 40px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title> votepledge :) </title>

</head>

<body></body></html>
```

First will make sure all of the image is displayed and its on right `resolution`; where as the second will stretch the image to cover `x` and `y` axis, so the image my look out of order.

Here is a [CSS Reference Guide](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Comment: This is extremely helpful, Praveen. My goal was to do the first version, so it's not distorted.
Forgive this super simple question, but where does the first block of code go within the HTML document? Thank you again for your patience. Very new to this.

Comment: That is using `External CSS` files, here's how to use it. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_css.asp  Drop a comment if you need anything else

Answer (score 0):

When you use `background-size: cover;` you are stretching the image in order to cover the whole element you are applying the style class to (in this case `html` tag). Because the image keeps its original propotions, some of the top and the bottom of the image may wont be visible. Try using other `background-size` options like `contain` or `auto`, but notice your left and right side of the background wont be covered now. You can fix it somehow by using `background-repeat-x: repeat`.

Maybe this a helpful approach:

```
html { 
        background: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/56fecd9704426225f7725b25/58699484197aea5283447865/59cf2b839f74567b7edf839d/1506750164505/votepledge_comingsoonpage_final_1920.png) repeat center center fixed; 
        -webkit-background-size: auto;
        -moz-background-size: auto;
        -o-background-size: auto;
        background-size: auto;
    }
```

Notice I did change `no-repeat` to `repeat` in the `background` definition.

I recomend you to read the [W3Schools CSS Backgrounds](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp) page and play a little with the css styles so you can find the solution that suites you better.